# In Linq-to-SQL, does IMultipleResults hit the database more than once?

Tags: c#, database, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a stored proc as follows :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMultipleResults
   @SomeID int
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM SomeTable1 where SomeColumn1 = @SomeID
   SELECT * FROM SomeTable2 where SomeColumn2 = @SomeID
   SELECT * FROM SomeTable3 where SomeColumn3 = @SomeID
   SELECT * FROM SomeTable4 where SomeColumn4 = @SomeID
END
```

Then I use the following code to execute and retrieve the data:

```
[Function(Name = "dbo.SPROCName")]
[ResultType(typeof(ResultSet1))]
[ResultType(typeof(ResultSet2))]
[ResultType(typeof(ResultSet3))]
[ResultType(typeof(ResultSet4))]
public IMultipleResults SomeMethod([Parameter(DbType = "INT")] int? SomeID
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), SomeID);
    return ((IMultipleResults)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

Now finally, to get each result, I execute something like :

```
public void SomeOtherMethod(int SomeID)
{
    DataContext1 context = new DataContext1 (dbConnString);
    IMultipleResults results = context.SomeMethod(SomeID);

    ResultSet1 resultSet1= results.GetResult().FirstOrDefault();
    IEnumerable resultSet2 = results.GetResult().ToList();
    IEnumerable resultSet3 = results.GetResult().ToList();
    ResultSet4 resultSet4= results.GetResult().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

My question is, does Linq-to-SQL execute the entire stored procedure once, then the `GetResult()` is used to get it from memory, or does it execute n queries (round trip db calls) where n is the number of select statements in the stored proc (4 in this example)?

The reason I'm asking is because the following line almost takes the same amount of time to execute even for large data:

```
IMultipleResults results = context.SomeMethod(SomeID);
```

but the following part takes some noticeable time when run where resultSet3 is a large amount of data :

```
IEnumerable resultSet3 = results.GetResult().ToList();
```

Comment: Should be pretty easy to find out: fire up SQL Server Profiler, and watch the traffic between your app and SQL Server ! I would bet that Linq-to-SQL will retrieve **all** result sets in a single call, and then just return whichever set you're asking for on the client side

Comment: It should hit the database once since SQL Server supports Multiple Active Result Sets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will certainly only be one round-trip to the database.  LinqToSQL has no visibility of what's inside the stored procedure it has to rely on the ResultType attributes you have applied being correct.

Internally LinqToSQL will execute the stored procedure and then open a data reader to retrieve the results.

For the `FirstOrDefault` cases it will retrieve the first item (if there is one) and then skip to the next result set using [IDataReader.NextResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.nextresult.aspx).  So even if resultSet1 is potentially large only the first row needs fetched over the network.

For the `ToList` cases the entire result set will be retrieved by the reader.  So if there's lot of data it will necessarily take longer.